# Getting Context inside the adapter of a RecyclerView

Tags: android

So, I am launching a "YouTube player" `onClick` of an item in the RecyclerView. However, here I have a problem:

```
Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(itemView.getContext(), DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, "cdgQpa1pUUE");
itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

where `itemView` is the View, and at here

```
createVideoIntent(itemView.getContext()
```

Android studio says:

> Wrong 1st Argument type found,'Android.content.Context', Required
>   'android.app.Activity'

How do I fix it? I tried the similar questions, but the solution in those was limited to Fragments and supportive libraries such as v4 and v7. Any help will be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
Activity activity = (Activity) itemView.getContext();
Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer
        .createVideoIntent(activity, DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, "cdgQpa1pUUE");
itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context context;

        public SampleAdapter(Context Mcontext) {
            this.context = Mcontext;
        }

        /* ... other methods ... */
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass down your activity to the Recycled View.

For example like this:

```
public MyAdapter(MyActivity activity){
   this.activity = activity;
}
```

later

```
YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(this.activity, DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, "cdgQpa1pUUE");
        itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```